# A current generated from electric generator turbine/motor forced externally to rotate in one direction

Tags: generator, electromagnetic, dynamo

How can an AC current generated from electric generator turbine/motor forced externally to rotate in one rotary direction be alternating, as it's just the reversed DC motor process generating force or rotary kinetics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: An alternator]

*Image source: [UMN](http://people.ece.umn.edu/users/riaz/animations/alternator.html).*

> ... as it's just the reversed DC motor process generating force or rotary kinetics?

If the generator is generating AC then it's not a DC machine and won't have a commutator and brushes. The alternating voltage comes from the alternating polarity of the rotor magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

With a stationary permanent magnet, when the coil rotates through the field that generates a voltage & current, as the coil continues to rotate the same field causes the current & voltage to be in the opposite direction.

One reason DC generators had commutators.